# How to test whether string contains multiple defined words in order?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and need to test whether multiple defined words are included in order.

For example the predefined words are:`["one", "two", "three"]`

So a string with: `"one two three"` should return true but a string with: `"three two one"` should return false.

My current regex looks like this: `new RegExp('\\bone\\b\\two\\b\\three\\b')`

Unfortunately this just checks if the words are present but doesn't care if they are in the right order.

Comment: Your regex _does_ care about the order. But it doesn't handle words in between, as well as before/after the checked words. 
Here's the solution: `new RegExp('.*\\bone\\b.*\\btwo\\b.*\\bthree\\b.*')`. Or dynamically: `new RegExp('.*\\b' + arr.join('\\b.*\\b') + '\\b.*')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use this regex

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
var regex = new RegExp(arr.join(".*"));
```

`arr.join(".*")` will make a regex `/one.*two.*three/`

Comment: + 1 for more maintainable code with the array join.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
var re = /one.*two.*three/
```

Example:

```
re.test('one two three'); // true
re.test('three two one'); // false
```

Comment: hey, can you make a chrome extension for http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=Hi%3F&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode?

Comment: great! Let me know by pinging me

Comment: OP could use word boundaries if needed.

Comment: @AmitJoki Hey I finished a beta version of the regex chrome extension. The link can be found by viewing my profile. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @hwnd it's awesome but, I'd like to see a button "Go!", on click of which the regex will be explained and not on blur event. Also, it would be nice if it was in a format which I could copy and paste as is in the SO editor, as it is a hectic work to align it.

Comment: @AmitJoki You can download and check out the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Sir please check these what's the error. I can't figure this out. The code don't pop up.

Here is the pop up click.

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-2x" onClick="click();"></i></a></li>
```

Here is the javascript codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.klaviyo.com/media/js/public/klaviyo_subscribe.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('icon-envelope icon-2x').on('click',function(){
     KlaviyoSubscribe.attachModalSignUp({
        list: 'g9cZtX',
        delay_seconds: 0.5,
        content: {
            clazz: ' klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX',
            header: "Interested in our Newsletter?",
            subheader: "Stay in the know with news and promotions.",
            button: "Subscribe",
            success: "Thanks! Check your email for a confirmation.",
            styles: '.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX {  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_header {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_subheader {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span {  background-color:#07234F;  background-image: none;   border-radius: 2px;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button:hover,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span:hover {  background-color:#2A4D85;  background-image: none; }.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_inner,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=text],.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=email] {  border-radius: 2px;}'
        }
    });
});
});
    </script>
```